# Could different outcomes have different physics in Wigner's friend?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-interpretations, non-linear-systems, schroedingers-cat

Could different outcomes have different physics in Wigner's friend?

Physicist Eugene Wigner said that consciousness was fundamental for physics and that laws of physics existed because of it. He said that "consciousness can change the usual laws of physics"

He also proposed the "Wigner's friend" mental experiment (analogue to Schrödinger's cat) where two observers could experience different realities or observe different outcomes for the same experiment.

But what about the laws of physics? Could these different realities even differ in their laws of nature?

Answer (score 0):

vengaq,

There is no evidence that consciousness has any relevance for physics.

In a "Wigner's friend" scenario the two observers do not experience different realities or different outcomes for the same experiment. They simply use different descriptions of the experiment based on the information available to them. The observer inside the lab knows the result of the measurement performed there (say a spin measurement) so, from his point of view, the particle is in a state of defined spin on that axis. The outside observer does not know the measurement result so the only thing he can say is that if the spin was found to be "up" the inside observer knows it is "up" and if the spin was found to be "down" the inside observer knows it is "down". When the outside observer enters the lab he will agree with the inside observer on the measurement outcome. This is all there is to this thought experiment.

Comment: but what about this: https://www.google.com/amp/s/www.technologyreview.com/s/613092/a-quantum-experiment-suggests-theres-no-such-thing-as-objective-reality/amp/? Isn't that suggesting that Wigner and his friend would measure different outcomes or results? (one measures a definite outcome while the other proves that the system is in superposition)

Comment: In this paper it is assumed that photons are observers. This is not even wrong.